# Vue CLI - как избавиться хэша (/#/) в url

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

установил Vue CLI делаю сборку, запускаю приложение.

При этом URL имеет такой вид: http://localhost:8080**/#/**

Можно ли настроить чтобы приложение имело нормальный адрес, вида: http://localhost:8080

--

В документации к VueCLI говорится что можно убрать хэш с помощью настроек веб-сервера, но что делать если я захочу залить приложение к примеру на "GitHub Pages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Vue-Router` поставить `mode: 'history'`, хэша не будет.

[Документация](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Пофиксил следующим образом:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

заменил на

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

--

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})
```

заменил на

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
```